# "special offers" category

Tags: discount, promotions

I would create a dynamic category "special offers" that contains all discounted products:

- discounts of single products;
- global discounts (menu "promotions" / "catalog price rules").

How I can copy, automatically, discounted products to "special offers" category?

I thought to crontab process.. or plugin (ok, but which event for global discounts?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this thing by cron job:s

First,you **need to get list of products which have discounts**,then assign those products in **special category**

So.first to ***fetch product collection and  filter those products*** which have `final_price` is less that `price` field.

```
  $Collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addFinalPrice()
                        ->getSelect()
                        ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price');
// Get product ids 
$productIds=$Collection->getAllIds();
$categoryId = 'Your Category_Ids';  /
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)->load($categoryId);
//get the current products
$products = $category->getProductsPosition();

foreach ($productIds as $id){
    $products[$id] = 1;//you can put any other position number instead of 1.
}
//attach all the products to the category
$category->setPostedProducts($products);
//save the category.
$category->save();
```

**Code is not tested.but concept is right**

Comment: Ok.. I tested this snippet and I see that it works also with global promo. Then, it means that magento update "final_price" field also with this type of promo, not only with discount on single item. Thanks!